# Php exec on linux machine is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, linux

So I am writing a simple little panel so that my friends can restart their server without having to go through terminal to do so. I am currently running into this problem though. When I click on one of the buttons it does not execute the linux command on the local machine. If anyone could help me that would be great, also sorry if the code is all over the place.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['button']))
    {
         $command = '/etc/init.d/darkrp start'
         $executecommand = shell_exec($command);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['button1']))
    {
         $command = '/etc/init.d/darkrp stop'
         $executecommand = shell_exec($command);
    }

    if (isset($_POST['button2']))
    {
         $command = '/etc/init.d/darkrp restart'
         $executecommand = shell_exec($command);
    }
?>
<html>
<body>

<button name="button" onclick="myFunction()">Start</button>
<button name="button1" onclick="myFunction1()">Stop</button>
<button name="button2" onclick="myFunction1()">Restart</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Server started!";
}

function myFunction1() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Server stopped!";
}

function myFunction2() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Server restarted!";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Break it down in smaller parts. Just make a script that is executing the shell command and see if that part works. Each part should work on it's own before you start putting it all together. My guess is that the Apache user doesn't have the permission to start and stop services.

Comment: by default form elements use the `GET` protocol, wrap your buttons in a `<form action="" method="post"> ... </form>`, in addition your javascript fires before your posting so your giving them false information, output what the shell is returning for more accurate reporting.

Comment: Does the user under which your webserver runs have permissions to execute those files?

Comment: This is what it says towards the permissions.
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 454 Jul 14 17:11 darkrp